# Is it possible to explicitly import builtins (DOM globals for example)?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

The current scenario involves rollup (and iife parameters), however I don't believe it's a question for rollup *and* typescript.

I'd like to do something like:
`import { document } from "[wherever dom lives]";`

Comment: I think more details and clarifications are needed for this question

Comment: Even though @Evaldas Buinauskas has already mentioned, confirmed, what I had suspected I'd be happy to provide further details as required. If you could help me understand what is unclear to you I'll make those changes.

Comment: Explicit imports are a significant improvement to ambient type declarations IMO. Things like `MessageChannel`, `Fetch` can be overridden by other ambient types and it's quite frustrating to track those declarations down. Also improves the ergonomics of dependency injecting builtins for unit testing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't import them explicitly as they're built in.

Comment: I was afraid of that. I guess this might be a problem for rollup.